# How do I make recyclerView that retrives data from firebase, using getKey()?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I would like to know how can I do a recyclerView that shows data that I got from this database reference:

```
    Salas= new ArrayList<String>(); 
DatabaseReference referenceSalas = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("salas/");   
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("usuarios/");
    FirebaseAuth autenticacao = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    String emailUsu = autenticacao.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
    reference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(emailUsu).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                nomeProf = datas.child("nome").getValue().toString();
                referenceSalas.orderByChild("nomeProf").equalTo(nomeProf).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Salas.add(datas.getKey());

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        throw databaseError.toException();
                    }
                });

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
```

I tried to do the RecyclerView like this:

```
public class salasFragment extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView mRecycleViewSalas;
private adapterSalas adapterSalas;
private ArrayList<salas> listaSalas= new ArrayList<>();
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private TextView txtSalas, txtTeste;
private String nomeProf;
private String teste="", piru;
private DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("usuarios/");
private DatabaseReference referenceSalas = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("salas/");
private  ValueEventListener valueEventListenerSalas;

ArrayList<String> salasAula = new ArrayList<String>();

public salasFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_salas, container, false);

    final Context context = view.getContext();
    txtSalas= view.findViewById(R.id.txtSalas);
    txtTeste= view.findViewById(R.id.txtTeste);


    mRecycleViewSalas= view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerSalas);

    adapterSalas= new adapterSalas(listaSalas, context);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    mRecycleViewSalas.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mRecycleViewSalas.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecycleViewSalas.setAdapter(adapterSalas);

    return view; }

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    recuperarSalas();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    reference.removeEventListener(valueEventListenerSalas);
}

public void recuperarSalas(){

    FirebaseAuth autenticacao = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    String emailUsu = autenticacao.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
   valueEventListenerSalas = reference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(emailUsu).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                nomeProf = datas.child("nome").getValue().toString();
                referenceSalas.orderByChild("nomeProf").equalTo(nomeProf).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                            salas salas=datas.getKey(salas.class);
                            listaSalas.add(salas);

                        }
                        adapterSalas.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        throw databaseError.toException();
                    }
                });

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
}
```

}

my adapter:

```
public class adapterSalas extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapterSalas.myViewHolder> {
private List<salas> Salas;
private Context context;

public adapterSalas(List<salas> listaSalas, Context c ) {
    this.Salas= listaSalas;
    this.context = c;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    View itemLista = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_salas, parent, false);
    return new myViewHolder(itemLista);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position) {

    salas sala = Salas.get(position);
    holder.btn1.setText(sala.getPrimeiro());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Salas.size();
}

public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    Button btn1;


    public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        btn1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    }
}


}
```

Although this line "salas salas=datas.getKey(salas.class);" does not work properly when I use "getKey", It only works when "getValue" is used. There is no way of me doing this project  with "getValue" instead of "getKey". So there is any way that can make this recyclerView works properly with "getKey" ?

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you got the data from the firebase already?

If you got the data in an arraylist already, simply plug it in an adapter (you will need to create a RecyclerView adapter, a class to describe the value of each RecyclerView items) and set it to the RecyclerView and you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

You can use FirebasRecyclerAdapter as you recyclerView adapter. check out this link for a guide on how to use it.

https://medium.com/android-grid/how-to-use-firebaserecycleradpater-with-latest-firebase-dependencies-in-android-aff7a33adb8b